# Tweetinvi doesn't work

Tags: linux, mono, tweetinvi

I am using mono develop on Ubuntu os.I downloaded Tweetinvi lib from nuget.This used to work on windows.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var appCredentials = new TwitterCredentials("AppCred", "AppCred");


        var authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCredentials);

        Process.Start(authenticationContext.AuthorizationURL);

        string pinCode = Console.ReadLine();



        var userCredentials = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(pinCode, authenticationContext);


        Auth.SetCredentials(userCredentials);


        var firstTweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("Hello World!");


    }
```

Now I get this exception : Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000015, in terminal.

I tried different versions of the Tweetinvi library and I got: System.TypeInitialization Exception,at
var authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCredentials);

This worked well in Xamarin Studio in Windows but I must do this in Linux.I guess I must add a reference or something so that ubuntu can open firefox and start authentication process.

Comment: Hello, could you confirm that you are trying to install the version 1.2 of Tweetinvi via nuget? Note that Mono (and therefore Xamarin on Linux) is supported started at Mono version 4.5. If you experience an issue with such version please let me know.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do.Also I tried to add the dlls to my packages directory with no luck.Tweetinvi works like a charm in Windows though.